# SwiftUI - How to hide window title on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

On macOS with new SwiftUI framework without `AppDelegate` / `SceneDelegate`, how do I hide the window title?

I found this article from Apple that describes how to do it for a Catalyst app but without that delegate now, how do I achieve this?

Link to article - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/removing_the_title_bar_in_your_mac_app_built_with_mac_catalyst

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the following window style:

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
}
.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't hide the close, minimize, and maximize buttons. Is there any way to do that as well.

Answer (score 6):

Now it's:

```
WindowGroup {
  ContentView()
}
.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
```

Comment: Consider writing comments to existing correct but outdated answers

Comment: I don't have the reputation to make comments on other people's answers yet.

Comment: Its the same answer as the original but updated to current syntax lol.